# Reverting imported dictionary via QPushButton issues

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, pyqt5

I am having trouble understanding why a deep copy of a dictionary reverts back to original values when I run the `revert()` method once, but when I change values again, and run the `revert()` method again it changes the copied dictionaries values along with the original.

The dictionary/values are being imported from another file. I can only assume it is because the Test is being imported more than once.

Can someone help explain why this is happening and what can I do to avoid it?

Test.py

```
import ujson,copy

nested1 = {'1':None, '2':"String"}
nested2 = {'1':0.5123, '2':515}
diction = {'1':nested1, '2':nested2}

copyDiction = ujson.loads(ujson.dumps(diction))
copyOtherDiction = copy.deepcopy(diction)
```

Main.py

```
import Test
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Window,self).__init__(parent)
        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Change Value")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.changeMethod)
        self.revertbutton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Revert")
        self.revertbutton.clicked.connect(self.revert)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.revertbutton)
        widget.setLayout(layout)

    def changeMethod(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()
        if text.isdigit():
            Test.diction['1']['2'] = int(text)
        else:
            Test.diction['1']['2'] = text

    def revert(self):
        print(Test.diction)
        Test.diction = Test.copyDiction
        print(Test.diction)
        print(Test.copyDiction)

def main():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Could you explain what you get and what you want to get? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @eyllanesc In my post, I said that when I run revert method once, it reverts dictionary back to original, but running it again with new text, it changes both original and copied dictionary. When I make changes to dictionary, I want to be able to go back to the original from when it first started the program no matter how many times I change it

Comment: `Test.diction = Test.copyDiction` will assign the exact same object to `Test.diction` as to `Test.copyDiction`. Any changes made to `Test.diction` later on will effect `Test.copyDiction` as well. To prevent this you should make a deep copy of `Test.copyDiction` and assign the copy to `Test.diction`.

Comment: @Heike So make a deepcopy of a deepcopy?

Comment: Well yes. You are making a copy keeping one of the two as a reserve and modifying the other one so to reset the modyfied version you need to make a new copy of the unmodified version.